# MySql Delete Optimisation

Tags: mysql, sql-delete, database-optimization

Here is the query which I am trying to execute

```
DELETE FROM testmachine WHERE workdone != 0 AND timetaken < 1617215400 LIMIT 1000;
```

It is taking more than 50 sec to execute the Query. I want to increase the speed.

Is there any way to reduce the execution time?

Here is my column schema:

```
id  int UN AI PK
att text
ways    varchar(100)
mediuminv   text
mediumid    varchar(45)
timetaken   int
workdone    int
in_use  tinyint UN
status  tinyint
in  text
out text
```

Here is the index:

```
Index: idx_time_taken_work_done_in_use_status

Definition:

    Type    BTREE
    Unique  No
    Visible Yes
    Columns done
        time
        in_use
        status
```

TIA

Comment: *WHERE workdone != 0 AND timetaken < 1617215400* Does this condition is completely static? partially static (1617215400 alters)? completely dynamic?

Comment: @Akina it is partially static, workdone !=0 is static and  timetaken will vary

Comment: Is `workdone` values list 0/1 or it is more wide? Does this query is used for to delete all rows matched (without limitation) by chunks as a final goal?

Comment: @Akina it is more wide, storing part of timestamp

Comment: Test the time needed for: 1) creation for virtual generated column with the expression used in WHERE and the index by it 2) deletion using this column 3) drop the column and index. Maybe it will be more fast, especialy if you execute a lot of deletes?

Comment: @Akina can you please explain point 2

Answer (score 0):

If the query is used in somewhere like:

```sql
REPEAT
    DELETE FROM testmachine WHERE workdone != 0 AND timetaken < 1617215400 LIMIT 1000;
UNTIL !ROW_COUNT() END REPEAT;
```

then try

```sql
ALTER TABLE testmachine 
    ADD COLUMN flag BOOLEAN AS (workdone != 0 AND timetaken < 1617215400) VIRTUAL,
    ADD INDEX idx_flag (flag);

REPEAT
    DELETE FROM testmachine WHERE flag LIMIT 1000;
UNTIL !ROW_COUNT() END REPEAT;

ALTER TABLE testmachine
    DROP INDEX idx_flag,
    DROP COLUMN flag;
```